# Is there a way to check how many screens are plugged into one computer (JS/PHP)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I don't have code for this question. However I've been searching around trying to find a way to detect how many screens a visitor currently has. What I am trying to achieve is a JS or jQuery slideshow between 2 monitors. I am thinking the best way to go about doing this is to first find out how many screens, and the screens size.

I also thought of making a huge div that would spread across 2 screens but that won't work, I think.

Sorry I am not providing any code, but I was looking around and couldn't find anything on that on the net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you check for the screens themselves? Isn't it easier to just check the resolution? `$(window).width` for instance? Then you can create a slider for those resolutions.

Comment: Short answer, no there is'nt! Long answer, there surely is'nt as that would be OS specific. However you could probably detect if the browser for some strange reason had an aspect ratio of, say 32:9 etc.

Comment: I see well thanks everyone.. I thought it would be something like that. if window.width would have returned a width of both monitors then its might be doable.

Comment: window width returns just that, the window width, as in the browsers width. Javascript has `screen.width` which should return the width of the screen, but I doubt it will return the width of more than one screen, and having four screens myself, `screen.width` still returns only the width of one screen, not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript you only can get browser's window size, at least the user have the browser's window filling all the virtual desktop, you can "detect" the amount of screens. With "detect" I mean you can calculate using most common screen sizes statistics and some probability, is not completely impossible if you know all your users.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to detect the amount of monitors. You may only guess it according to the screen width.

Provide liquid design and let your visitor decide about the window width.